# put each element of an array in state and then show it to render ()

Tags: react-native, state, render

How do I put an array in a state and how do I show the result in render ()?

```
export default class UserList extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props); 
        this.state={  
          post:[
            {id:"0", author:"", delay:"", status:""},
            {id:"1", author:"", delay:"", status:""},
            {id:"2", author:"", delay:"", status:""}
 ]
}
putintostate(){
var author_array= ["Mark","Jess","Alice"]
var delay_array= ["12","13","14"]
var status_array= ["1","2","3"]
this.setState.post.map(new_dato=>this.setState.post.author(new_dato))
this.setState.post.map(new_dato=>this.setState.post.delay_array(new_dato))
this.setState.post.map(new_dato=>this.setState.post.status_array(new_dato))
}
 componentDidMount() {
    this.putintostate()  
  }
render(){
return(
<text>{this.state.post.author}<Text>
<text>{this.state.post.delay}<Text>
<text>{this.state.post.status}<Text>

)}
```

i want to put the first element of the author_array array in the state post with id = 1 in the cmapo auhtor. I want as output:

```
            id:"0", author:"Mark", delay:"12", status:"1"
            id:"1", author:"Jess", delay:"13", status:"2"
            id:"2", author:"Alice", delay:"14", status:"3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not implement any guards for the following. I expect that all three arrays contain the same number of elements. You could then implement it as follows.

```js
const author_array = ["Mark", "Jess", "Alice"]
const delay_array = ["12", "13", "14"]
const status_array = ["1", "2", "3"]
const result = author_array.map((item, index) =>
  ({
    id: index.toString(),
    author: item,
    delay: delay_array[index],
    status: status_array[index]
  }));
```

Then, set the new state.

```js
this.setState({post: result});
```

Then, map over the state in the `render` function and render whatever you want. I will use a text component in my example.

```js
render(){
    return(
       <View>
        {
            this.state.post.map(item => {
               return <>
                <Text>{this.state.post.author}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.post.delay}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.post.status}</Text>
               </>
            })
        }
       </View>
)}
```

[Here is a little snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/class-component).